# How to rename a column in a ts object

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with objects of class ts in R.

Is there code I can use to change column names in this kind of an object?

For a data frame, I would use something like this:

```
Shipper_City <- rename(Shipper_City,"ShipCity_Old" = "ShipCity")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the 'colnames()' function

You want to use `colnames()`, because you're dealing with a matrix in case of a `ts` object:

```
colnames(data) <- c("ColName1", "ColName2")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I created that might be useful for you.

```
rename.ts <- function(ts, ...){
  if (inherits(ts, "mts")) {
    x <- list(...)
    old_names <- names(x)
    if (all(old_names %in% colnames(ts))) {
      id_old_names <- which(old_names %in% colnames(ts))
      colnames(ts)[id_old_names] <- unname(unlist(x)) 
    } else {
      stop("You must provide valid column names")
    }
  } else {
    stop("You must provide a mts object as argument")
  }
  ts
}
# Example
mts <- ts(data = mtcars, start = 2013, frequency = 4)
rename.ts(mts, "mpg" = "mpg2", "cyl" = "cyl2")
```